# Reroll dice when double occurs but wait for user interaction

Tags: javascript

```
function playgame() {
    rollDice(); //two dice rolls
    drawDice(); //displays the dice
    setPosition(); //update player position
    pastGo(); //checks if player went past GO
    movePiece(); //moves monopoly board piece to where it landed
    checkDouble(); //if double go back to playgame(), so changeTurn() wil not run. 
    changeTurn();
};
```

The function `playgame()` initially runs when the player presses "Roll Dice" button.
When a double occurs the function is called, but this happens without interaction with the player.

I want to change the text of the "Roll Dice" button  to "Roll Again" and run `playgame()` only when the player presses the "Roll Again" button. So what code needs to go in `checkDouble()`?

Comment: Something along the lines of : `if (confirm('Roll again?')){playGame();}`

Comment: @codehorse, I have that part, but i only want to go to playgame() with the users interaction. The player needs to know that he got a double and needs to roll again. If i go straight to playgame, the player never knew he got a double.

Comment: @tewathia yes something along those lines, only the confirmation part needs to be seamless, so rather than an alert prompt for instance, i want to just change the text from the "roll dice" button to "roll again" and wait for user to press that.

Comment: Then try: `$('#diceButton').text('Roll Again').click(function(){playGame();});`. Also, you might want to put your `changeTurn` call inside the `checkDouble` function(`if (RollAgainClicked) {playGame();} else {changeTurn();}`)

Comment: Yes your answer seems right. I will try and get it to work now. Will confirm it as soon as it works.

Comment: I can confirm it worked, thanks tewathia.